# OpenOffice migration: supported Office document formats?

Tags: openoffice

We're considering a number of migration options for OpenOffice at the moment.

Can anyone confirm if OpenOffice is capable of opening and converting all of the following Office file formats?

- `doc` (97-2003)
- `docx` (2007-)
- `ppt`
- `pptx`
- `xls`
- `xlsx`

Comment: Formats are more or less supported, however you will probably have some problems with elements within a file, for example equations in word documents usually don't map good when opened in OO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  OpenOffice.org can read and write all those file formats.

Once in a while I do encounter a document that doesn't convert very well, but these are usually documents that are very complex and so other programs (e.g., WordPerfect Office) also have a little trouble with them.

Interoperability is generally quite good, but from any product to any other product there can be challenges with file format conversions (in any direction), so I recommend that you install OpenOffice.org on one of your computers and try loading a variety of your documents, spreadsheets, and presentations to see if there are any major issues right-off-the-bat.